# Generic pipe and filters

Tags: c++, template, inheritance, boost

I made a template pipe and filters to replace an old pipe and filters implementation that used inheritance and had a very heavy base class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <list>

template <typename Data>
class pipeline {
    typedef boost::function<Data(Data)> filter_function;
    typedef std::list<filter_function> filter_list;
    filter_list m_list;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(T t) {
        m_list.push_back(boost::bind(&T::filter, t, _1));
    }

    Data run(Data data) {
        typedef typename filter_list::iterator iter;
        iter end = m_list.end();

        for(iter it = m_list.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
            data = (*it)(data);
        }

        return data;
    }
};

struct foo {
    int filter(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pipeline<int> pipe;
    foo f;
    pipe.add(f);
    std::cout << pipe.run(0);
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

Except the fact that `add()` is a template, are there any issues anyone sees with this approach?

Comment: The answers really depend on what C++ standard you have access to. With C++11, you could throw boost away.

Answer (score 7):

- As `run()` is several lines long, it should be defined outside the class.  Anything defined inside is automatically inlined.
- Depending on the size of `data` when passing by value, it may be best to pass it to `run()` by `const&`, modify a local copy, and return that.  RVO should still kick in.
- Is there a significance to the name `foo` here?  If not, it should be more accurate *and* start with a capital letter as it's a user-defined type.  The capitalization also applies to `pipeline`.
- `iter end = m_list.end();` seems pointless here.  You can just use `m_list.end()` inside the loop statement.

  As `m_list` is not being modified inside the loop, you can instead use `cbegin()` and `cend()` for const-correctness.

  If you have C++11, you can use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) to replace the defined iterator inside the loop statement.
- Your "pause" is okay, but you can also use `std::cin.get()` to do the same thing.

Comment: `start with a capital letter as it's a user-defined type. The capitalization also applies to pipeline.` If you could provide a reference here, it would be a kick in the nuts for my colleagues, claiming that "if STL does it, it's correct".

Comment: @Vorac: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881915/why-does-the-stl-boost-c-coding-style-differ-so-much-from-everyone-elses) might help, which also includes a quote from Stroustrup.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::vector` instead of `std::list` may be more efficient (both for speed and memory allocation).
Advantages are explained in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238008/relative-performance-of-stdvector-vs-stdlist-vs-stdslist) question.

Just change

```
typedef std::list<filter_function> filter_list;
```

to

```
typedef std::vector<filter_function> filter_list;
```